# batch file to create subfolder structure within existing folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, explorer

I want to create the following folder structure at work. I have to add an 'archived emails' directory, sorted by year, then month within 50(ish) folders that are individual towns. Folder in bold already exists:

- **Town**

  - Archived emails

    - YYYY

      - 01JanYYYY
      - 02FebYYYY
      - 03MarYYYY

etc etc

the preceding 01,02,03 in the months folder is so the months are sorted in explorer properly. Could someone help me out with writing up the batch file please? I'm not too good with the syntax.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For creating a folder simply use

```
md "C:\[PATH-TO-TOWN]\Archived emails"
```

for example

[Here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting) you have a nice resource for batch scripting. You can find there also a neat description of how to make a loop in batch scripts.